# week number returns previous year last week number for january fist week in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am facing one issue while fetching the week number for 2016-01-01(fist week) in mysql. it return 53 if i use `week()` function or `weekofyear()` function . I have to get as 1 since I am linking the **weeknumber** in my project in other places and if it returns 1 the next week number also should be adjusted according to that. Kindly any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) says:

> If the week containing January 1 has 4 or more days in the new year,
>   it is week 1.
>
> Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year, and the next week
>   is week 1.

So you can provide the `mode` to the week function.

```
Mode   First day of week    Range   Week 1 is the first week …
0      Sunday               0-53    with a Sunday in this year
1      Monday               0-53    with 4 or more days this year
2      Sunday               1-53    with a Sunday in this year
3      Monday               1-53    with 4 or more days this year
4      Sunday               0-53    with 4 or more days this year
5      Monday               0-53    with a Monday in this year
6      Sunday               1-53    with 4 or more days this year
7      Monday               1-53    with a Monday in this year
```

Something like this:

```
select WEEK('2016-01-01',0) + 1;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/39494)**

Comment: and what about this **select WEEK('2016-01-04',0) + 1;** ?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy:- As per what OP has asked, it would be week 2. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/39499

Comment: if he mean  **2016-01-01** give him the first week, also he need the second week begin from  **2016-01-08**

Comment: @GoudaElalfy:- No, as per what I understood and the problem which I have seen in past(*which is very usual at year starting*), many users get this issue as the functions give the week of the last year. As per my understanding OP doesn't want to change the week setting. S/she just wants to get the 1 and 2nd day of this year in the new week. Will wait for OP to respond(*if I missed it*)